# Public Network for Vagrant using libvirt

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, libvirt

I am trying to create a virtual machine using libvirt and Vagrant. I am successful in creating a VM with private networking, but when I try using public Networking, the virtual machine creation fails with the below errors. Any suggestions would be indeed helpful.

```
==> libvirtpublic: Starting domain.
There was an error talking to Libvirt. The error message is shown
below:

Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: Unable to add bridge wlp5s0 port vnet1: Operation not supported
```

This is my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'libvirt'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    ##### DEFINE VM #####
    config.vm.define "libvirtpublic" do |config|
    config.vm.hostname = "libvirtpublic"
    config.vm.box = "centos/7"
    config.vm.box_check_update = false
    config.vm.network :public_network,
      :dev => "wlp5s0",
      :mode => "bridge",
      :type => "bridge"
    config.vm.provider :libvirt do |v|
      v.memory = 2048
      v.cpus = 2
    end
   end
end
```

My environment details are:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

The bridge network configuration in your Vagrantfile is trying to use a wireless device and it is not supported.

To quote from libvirt documentation https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Bridged_networking_.28aka_.22shared_physical_device.22.29

> Important Note: Unfortunately, wireless interfaces cannot be attached to a Linux host bridge, so if your connection to the external network is via a wireless interface ("wlanX"), you will not be able to use this mode of networking for your guests.